# Multiple Regression in Python (with Factor Selection)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

All the threads that I've read with respect to Multiple Regression in Python mostly recommend the OLS function within Statsmodels. Here's the problem that I am encountering, I am trying to explain a fund's returns (HYFAX highlighted in green) by regressing its returns against 14 independent variables that could explain the returns of this fund. This should have a significant F test and spits out the best fit model with the highest adjusted R squared after going through the step by step iterations of the factors. Is there a way to do that in python?

[Fund returns vs Factors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5f8r.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to see the results from your model fit. Heres an example with 1 predictor, but easily extendable to 14:

Import statsmodels and specify the model you want to build (this is where you'd include your 14 predictors):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

#read in your data however you want and assign your y, x1...x14 variables

model = sm.OLS(x, y)
```

Fit the model:

```
results = model.fit()
```

Now just display a summary of your model fit:

```
print(results.summary())
```

That will give you your adjusted R squared value, F test value, beta weights etc. Should look something like this:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      x   R-squared:                       0.601
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.594
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     87.38
Date:                Wed, 24 Aug 2016   Prob (F-statistic):           3.56e-13
Time:                        19:51:25   Log-Likelihood:                -301.81
No. Observations:                  59   AIC:                             605.6
Df Residuals:                      58   BIC:                             607.7
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
y              0.8095      0.087      9.348      0.000         0.636     0.983
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.119   Durbin-Watson:                   1.607
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.942   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.178
Skew:                          -0.099   Prob(JB):                        0.915
Kurtosis:                       2.818   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================
```